# How to export table to excel with MySQL PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I have a table which is quite large having over 100k rows, and I want to export it to excel. How can i do that? I tried the export to excel function on mysql phpmyadmin however it takes forever. Is there an alternative way on how to do this?

Comment: Why you are posting same question again you can  edit previous one if you forgot to add any detail [*How to export table to excel from mysql database?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211692/how-to-export-table-to-excel-from-mysql-database)