# How to export table to excel from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin, export

I have a table in mysql which is quite big for having over 100k rows and I want to export it to excel. However, I tried the export to excel function on phpmyadmin but it takes forever to dump the excel file. It's not even dumping. The error is always, "the connection is reset". Is there an alternative way on how to do this??

Comment: 100,000 rows will require either an OfficeOpenXML-format .xlsx file, or 2 worksheets in a BIFF-format .xls file, because an xls file can have a maximum of 65,536 rows per worksheet

Comment: what about reading all the rows with php and use this to export as a excel file https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/01-Getting-Started.md

Comment: Dump it to a csv file.

Comment: @MarkBaker Actually, I was able to figure out something and deleted some rows now it was down 40k. How am I supposed to export the table?

Comment: Depends if you want a real Excel format file, or if a csv file is adequate

Comment: thanks guys! Ill try to export it as csv file and ill let you know :D @MarkBaker @ tonyhopkinson @ jycr753

Comment: it actually succeeded, however i need it to have a format as excel type format. with fields separated on each columns... csv copies everything in one column only and separated through commas..that's not what i need :(

Comment: Use a tab-separator rather than a comma for better reading by MS Excel

Answer (score 6):

First, 100k rows in Excel sounds like a horrible idea and of course it'll take awhile. This is going to take awhile just to open. If you MUST do this try:

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This should give you a file called: `/tmp/orders.csv` which will open in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness of your export is likely due to the server on which phpmyadmin runs. I regularly export millions of rows with surprising speed.

If you have access to the file system of your database server, this is a very fast way of converting to .csv, which in turn can be opened by Excel.

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

See this: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `OUTFILE` method before to do this:

```
SELECT
    'First Name',
    'Last Name',
    'Email Address'
UNION
SELECT
    First_Name,
    Last_Name,
    Email
INTO OUTFILE
    '/tmp/data_2012-05-03.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
FROM
    `data`
WHERE
    Reg_Date >= '2012-05-02 00:00:00' AND
    Reg_Date <= '2012-05-02 23:59:59' AND
    Email_Status = 1;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. May i know where did you execute this code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.